# Create Form with method class constructor C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop, methods

I have a class with method `NewForm` below:

```
class cFormInteraction
{
    public static void NewForm(Form fm)
    {
        if (fm is null)
        {
            fm = new Form();
            fm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

In `formMain`, I want to create form I want with Code like:

```
public static FormWantToShow FW;  
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cFormInteraction.NewForm(FW);
    }
```

I want to solve the problem:

```
if (fm is null)
        {
            fm = new Form(); // -> How i make the program understand and new the form i transmisson in.
            fm.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming every form you want to show has a parameterless constructor, you could do this via a generic method with a `ref` parameter.

The generic aspect allows the `NewForm` method to know what form type to create, and the `ref` parameter allows the calling code to store the reference to the newly-created form to be stored in a field.

```cs
static class FormInteraction
{
    public static void NewForm<T>(ref T fm)
        where T : Form, new()
    {
        if (fm is null)
        {
            fm = new T();
            fm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the calling code:

```cs
public static FormWantToShow form;  
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormInteraction.NewForm(ref form);
}
```

(I've changed the names to follow normal C# naming conventions.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a bit of an obfuscation to do the `null` check in the `NewForm` method.

It also seems weird that the name of that method is `NewForm` when it might not actually create a form.

It's also odd that it shows the form too without having that in the name.

It seems to me, then, that the code should be like this:

```
static class FormInteraction
{
    public static T NewAndShowForm<T>()
        where T : Form, new()
    {
        var fm = new T();
        fm.Show();
        return fm;
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
public static FormWantToShow form;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form != null)
    {
        form = FormInteraction.NewAndShowForm<FormWantToShow>();
    }
}
```